# How can I configure Logback to log different levels for a logger to different destinations?

Tags: java, logging, logback

How can I configure [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch) to log different levels for a logger to different destinations?

For example, given the following Logback configuration, will Logback record `INFO` messages to `STDOUT` and `ERROR` messages to `STDERR`?

(Note that this example is a variation of example `logback-examples/src/main/java/chapters/configuration/sample4.xml` shown in [Chapter 3:  Logback Configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)).

```xml
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT"
   class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <encoder>
     <pattern>
        %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="STDERR"
   class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <encoder>
     <pattern>
        %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
    <target>System.err</target>
  </appender>
  <!-- What is the effective level of "chapters.configuration"? -->
  <logger name="chapters.configuration" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="chapters.configuration" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
  </logger>

  <!-- turn OFF all logging (children can override) -->
  <root level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: in a pop quiz i would say - the higher one :) , but seriously, what does your console/stdout say if you log on both levels?

Comment: On second thought, I think the question that I'm more interested in answering is, "How can I log different levels for a logger to different destinations"?

Comment: You might like the [filter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24141208/581205) I've created.

Comment: @kostja It's the right answer. `levels are ordered as follows: TRACE < DEBUG < INFO <  WARN < ERROR.`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Update: For an all configuration based approach using Groovy see [Dean Hiller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653062#answer-13233538).

--

You can do some interesting things with [Logback filters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html). The below configuration will only print warn and error messages to stderr, and everything else to stdout.

**logback.xml**

```xml
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <target>System.out</target>
  <filter class="com.foo.StdOutFilter" />
   ...
</appender>

<appender name="stderr" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <target>System.err</target>
  <filter class="com.foo.ErrOutFilter" />
   ...
</appender>

<logger name="mylogger" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    <appender-ref ref="stderr" />
</logger>
```

**com.foo.StdOutFilter**

```
public class StdOutFilter extends ch.qos.logback.core.filter.AbstractMatcherFilter
{

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Object event)
    {
        if (!isStarted())
        {
            return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }

        LoggingEvent loggingEvent = (LoggingEvent) event;

        List<Level> eventsToKeep = Arrays.asList(Level.TRACE, Level.DEBUG, Level.INFO);
        if (eventsToKeep.contains(loggingEvent.getLevel()))
        {
            return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }
        else
        {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }
    }

}
```

**com.foo.ErrOutFilter**

```
public class ErrOutFilter extends ch.qos.logback.core.filter.AbstractMatcherFilter
{

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Object event)
    {
        if (!isStarted())
        {
            return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }

        LoggingEvent loggingEvent = (LoggingEvent) event;

        List<Level> eventsToKeep = Arrays.asList(Level.WARN, Level.ERROR);
        if (eventsToKeep.contains(loggingEvent.getLevel()))
        {
            return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }
        else
        {
            return FilterReply.DENY;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also use http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#levelFilter which will implement the classes for you..

Comment: @Odelya Yes, you can use the level filter but you'll need to define multiple filters as the configuration only accepts a SINGLE level to listen for.

Comment: You are right - I wrote in the end my own implementation but only one filter for all instead of 2. My filter retrieve levels string as parameter

Comment: @Uriah http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#thresholdFilter will take a range, instead of a single level

Comment: @AntonyStubbs Depends on the level of granularity you want to handle per appender. Using a threshold filter and adding additivity="false" the correct the appenders should work too.

Comment: Correct, but yecch!!! Such a simple requirement should not require Java programming.

Comment: you don't need the filter for stderr.  See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179773/logback-thresholdfilter-how-todo-the-opposite

Comment: I KNOW there is a way to write the above without writing your own filters as I ran into it once and used it and now I can't find it anymore.

Comment: posted it below for those who don't want to have java code for filtering.

Answer (score 95):

I believe this would be the simplest solution:

```xml
<configuration>
    <contextName>selenium-plugin</contextName>
    <!-- Logging configuration -->  
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <Target>System.out</Target>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%level] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <Target>System.err</Target>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder> 
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%level] [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern> 
        </encoder> 
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You want to use `ThresholdFilter`s instead.

Comment: yeah, that one only does info level when you want info, debug and trace to be logged to stdout but instead are ignored, right?

Comment: This eats debug and trace?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Given the use of  `<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">` what's the actual role of  specifying `<root level="INFO"> <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> <appender-ref ref="STDERR" /> </root>` in logback.xml?

Comment: why dates are not printing using this logback.xml? I see only time is printing. How to fix it?

Comment: Just what I needed, each appender is used for it's own log level! Also tried with 3 different appenders and 3 different log levels, and it works as expected.

Comment: When I add this I get a lot of internal logback.classic logs such as `00:38:15,527 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]`. Removing the `<filter>` removes the logs so this is definitely the cause. This seems to only happen when i use the `ConsoleAppender` since it doesn't add the logs to my `FileAppender`.

Comment: Figured it out - `<onMatch>` and `<onMismatch>` are not defined for `ThresholdFilter`. Simply remove them and it will work as intended.

Answer (score 60):

**Solution based on configuration only**, with a ThresoldFilter and LevelFilters to keep things **really simple to understand** :

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.err</target>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
          <level>WARN</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>DEBUG</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>INFO</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>TRACE</level>
          <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>WARN</level>
          <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
          <level>ERROR</level>
          <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: A bit verbose, but I like this solution because it's very simple and readable.

Comment: @Gondy Why verbose? You can use only `ThresoldFilter`.

Comment: Why not use `ThresoldFilter` to STDOUT, instead of using five `LevelFilter`?

Comment: @Alex78191, @ tonarimochi As far as I can remember, ThresholdFilter can be used to accept or reject logs with a level higher than the specified level (WARN), but not vice versa. So you can't use it to filter logs lower than WARN.

But if I'm wrong feel free to improve this answer or submit a new one.

Answer (score 36):

okay, here is my favorite xml way of doing it.  I do this for the eclipse version so I can

- click on stuff to take me to the log statements and
- see info and below in black and warn/severe in red

and for some reason SO is not showing this all properly but most seems to be there...

```xml
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">      
          <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.GEventEvaluator"> 
            <expression>
               e.level.toInt() &lt;= INFO.toInt()
            </expression>
          </evaluator>
          <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
          <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %X{sessionid}-%X{user} %caller{1} %-4level: %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter"> 
            <level>warn</level>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %X{sessionid}-%X{user} %caller{1} %-4level: %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <target>System.err</target>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDERR"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is the best filtering solution to separate trace debug info from warn and error

Comment: what would the `logback.groovy` version of this look line?

Answer (score 21):

The simplest solution is to use `ThresholdFilter` on the appenders:

```
    <appender name="..." class="...">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
```

Full example:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %-5level: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
        <target>System.err</target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %-5level: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Update: As Mike pointed out in the comment, messages with ERROR level are printed here both to STDOUT and STDERR. Not sure what was the OP's intent, though. You can try Mike's answer if this is not what you wanted.

Comment: I'm using logger and root. Appenders in logger getting executed but appenders in root are not getting called.

Comment: Gangadhar, set additivity="true" in your child logger (you overrided the default).

Comment: Thanks... important not to forget the <target> tag in the STDERR appender!  But there is also a problem with this: ALL the output above the filter level is printed... but with stdout you want the ERROR level (and above) NOT to be printed... see my solution which combines this with  S Hébert's answer...

Answer (score 10):

This is the configuration that I use, which works fine, it is based on XML + JaninoEventEvaluator (requires the [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home) library to be added to Classpath)

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date | [%-5level] in [%file:%line] - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator">
            <expression>
                level &lt;= INFO
            </expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
    </filter>
</appender>
<appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.err</target>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date | [%-5level] in [%file:%line] - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 9):

I use logback.groovy to configure my logback but you can do it with xml config as well:

```
import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.*
import static ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply.DENY
import static ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply.NEUTRAL
import ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.GEventEvaluator
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter

def patternExpression = "%date{ISO8601} [%5level] %msg%n"

appender("STDERR", ConsoleAppender) {
    filter(EvaluatorFilter) {
      evaluator(GEventEvaluator) {
        expression = 'e.level.toInt() >= WARN.toInt()'
      }
      onMatch = NEUTRAL
      onMismatch = DENY
    }
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
      pattern = patternExpression
    }
    target = "System.err"
  }

appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
    filter(EvaluatorFilter) {
      evaluator(GEventEvaluator) {
        expression = 'e.level.toInt() < WARN.toInt()'
      }
      onMismatch = DENY
      onMatch = NEUTRAL
    }
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
      pattern = patternExpression
    }
    target = "System.out"
}

logger("org.hibernate.type", WARN)
logger("org.hibernate", WARN)
logger("org.springframework", WARN)

root(INFO,["STDERR","STDOUT"])
```

I think to use GEventEvaluator is simplier because there is no need to create filter classes.
I apologize for my English!

Answer (score 6):

I take no credit for this answer, as it's merely a combination of the best two answers above: that of X. Wo Satuk and that of Sébastien Helbert: `ThresholdFilter` is lovely but you can't configure it to have an upper level as well as a lower level*, but combining it with two `LevelFilters` set to "DENY" `WARN` and `ERROR` works a treat.

**Very important**: do not forget the `<target>System.err</target>` tag in the STDERR appender: my omission of it had me frustrated for a few minutes.

```
<configuration>
    <timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M\(%line\)
                - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
        </filter>
        <target>System.err</target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M\(%line\)
                - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

* it does however have a method `decide` in the [API](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/filter/ThresholdFilter.html#decide(ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent)) but I haven't a clue how you'd use it in this context.

Comment: This is indeed the best solution, combining ThresholdFilter and LevelFilter!

Comment: what is         <target>System.err</target>
 for?

Comment: Credit is deserved for this answer which cleverly combines existing knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Try this. You can just use built-in `ThresholdFilter` and `LevelFilter`. No need to create your own filters programmically. In this example WARN and ERROR levels are logged to System.err and rest to System.out:

```
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- deny ERROR level -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <!-- deny WARN level -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <target>System.out</target>
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>${msg_pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="stderr" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- deny all events with a level below WARN, that is INFO, DEBUG and TRACE -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <target>System.err</target>
    <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>${msg_pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>   

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="stderr"/>
</root>

<root level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

No programming needed. configuration make your life easy.

Below is the configuration which logs different level of logs to different files

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="./logs" />

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-ERROR"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/app-error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/app-error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <!--output messages of exact level only -->
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE-INFO"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/app-info.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/app-info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>


    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
        <!--output messages of exact level only -->
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
</appender>


<appender name="FILE-DEBUG"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/app-debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/app-debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
        <!--output messages of exact level only -->
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-ALL"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/app.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="com.abc.xyz" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ALL" />
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
 <appender name="A1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${storm.log.dir}/${logfile.name}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${storm.log.dir}/${logfile.name}.%i</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>9</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ} %c{1} [%p] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
 </appender>

 <appender name="ACCESS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${storm.log.dir}/access.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${storm.log.dir}/access.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>9</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ} %c{1} [%p] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="METRICS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${storm.log.dir}/metrics.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${storm.log.dir}/logs/metrics.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>9</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>2MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d %-8r %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="A1"/>
  </root>

  <logger name="backtype.storm.security.auth.authorizer" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="backtype.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer" additivity="false" >
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="METRICS"/>
  </logger>

</configuration>

So here is the logback file in which I am not printing backtype.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer info level if i say additivity = "true" then for for all classes in backtype.* this rule will be applied
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to output colored messages of level "INFO" or higher to **console** and messages of level "WARN" or higher to **file**.

Your **logback.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>

            <!--output messages of exact level only-->
            <!--<onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>-->
            <!--<onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>-->
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>myfile.log</file>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
        </filter>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```