# Defining 1 logback file per level

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'd like to define a logback configuration file that will be able to :

- log DEBUG (and higher) things in debug.log
- log INFO (and higher) things in info.log

That is to say, when I call :

```
logger.warn("blah"); // Logs to both info.log and debug.log
logger.debug("bleh"); // Logs to debug.log only
```

Is it possible ?

I tried something like this, but it seems like when logback encounters multiple <root> tags, it only takes the last one :

```
<appender name="infoFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${LOGS_FOLDER}/info.log</File>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="debugFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>${LOGS_FOLDER}/debug.log</File>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="infoFile" />
</root>
<root level="DEBUG">
  <appender-ref ref="debugFile" />
</root>
```

Here, info.log contains debug-level logs :(

Note that I want to apply this behaviour on *every* of my packages.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653062/how-can-i-configure-logback-to-log-different-levels-for-a-logger-to-different-de

Comment: Oh yeah ... you're right !
Seems like level filter (http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#levelFilter) is what I need :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a levelFilter solved the problem

Example :

```
<appender name="infoFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <File>${LOGS_FOLDER}/info.log</File>
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
    <level>INFO</level>
    <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
  </filter>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="debugFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <File>${LOGS_FOLDER}/debug.log</File>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG"><!-- Using the lowest level here -->
  <appender-ref ref="debugFile" />
  <appender-ref ref="infoFile" />
</root>
```

Comment: Note that though the [docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#syntax) says there should be only 1 `root`, this seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: could you not use -

<root level="DEBUG">
  <appender-ref ref="infoFile" />
  <appender-ref ref="debugFile" />
</root>

Comment: @denov Sure, forgot to update the answer (now it's done)