# Configuring two logback appenders independently

Tags: configuration, logback, appender

I might be asking something trivial, but what I've tried doesn't seem to work. With my "MAIN" appender, I want to log all "info"s everywhere, except in a third-party package (let's call it `boring`), which produces too many of them (so I look at warnings only). Additionally, I want to log "debug"s in my `interesting` package. This works fine with the following `logback.groovy`:

```
root(INFO, ["MAIN"])
logger("interesting", DEBUG, ["MAIN"])
logger("boring", WARN, ["MAIN"])
```

Now I want to configure a different appender logging one level more like

```
root(DEBUG, ["DETAIL"])
logger("interesting", TRACE, ["DETAIL"])
logger("boring", INFO, ["DETAIL"])
```

This also works, but when I put both together, it doesn't. I can imagine that this is caused by the fact that each `Logger` is either on or off for a given level. I'm aware that for the behavior I want, the loggers in the "boring" package must be on the INFO level (because of the `DETAIL` appender) and that the messages for the `MAIN` appender are to be filtered, but I can't see how to configure this.

#### UPDATE

I see I was doing nearly everything wrong. The line

```
logger("interesting", DEBUG, ["MAIN"])
```

says nothing like "set the level to DEBUG for the MAIN appender and the package `interesting` and below"), it does two independent things instead:

- set the level to DEBUG for the package `interesting` and below
- add the MAIN appender to the "interesting" `Logger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be impossible without writing an own filter, which is fortunately pretty easy. I ended up with something like

```
root(DEBUG, ["DETAIL", "MAIN"])
// settings for the most detailed appender
logger("interesting", TRACE)
logger("boring", INFO)

appender("MAIN", ...) {
    ...
    filter = new MyFilter()
        .deny("boring", INFO)
        .accept("interesting", DEBUG)
        .deny("", DEBUG)
}
```

where `deny` and `accept` are my methods adding entries to `MyFilter`. The entries are evaluated sequentially, i.e.,

- in package `boring` and below, everything with level `INFO` or below gets denied
- in package `interesting` and below, everything with level `DEBUG` or above gets accepted
- otherwise, in any package, everything with level `DEBUG` or above gets denied

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653062).