# How to enable console logging while sending logs to logstash

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, logging, logstash-logback-encoder

I succeeded sending logs to my elk stack but now the issue is I don't have any standart output. it basically makes development hard. I wan't to be able to get logs on the console as well.

only log I get is as below, continuing logs are sent to logstash.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)
```

My `logback.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>host:port</destination>

        <reconnectionDelay>1 second</reconnectionDelay>
        <connectionTimeout>5 seconds</connectionTimeout>
        <keepAliveDuration>5 minutes</keepAliveDuration>
        <writeBufferSize>16384</writeBufferSize>
        <writeTimeout>1 minute</writeTimeout>

        <!-- encoder is required -->
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" >
            <customFields>{"app_name":"app name", "app_port": "app port"}</customFields>

        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="all">
        <appender-ref ref="stash" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>name</name>
    <description>desc</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.2</version>
            <!-- Use runtime scope if the project does not have any compile-time usage of logstash-logback-encoder,
                 such as usage of StructuredArguments/Markers or implementations such as
                 JsonProvider, AppenderListener, JsonFactoryDecorator, JsonGeneratorDecorator, etc
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.uuid/java-uuid-generator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!--used for skipping tests connection during build-->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

it also does not produce log files. Well it is no longer important to me as it streams to elk stack.

`application.properties`:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.web=INFO
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=20MB
logging.file.name=logs/app.log
logging.file.path=logs
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=7
```

Comment: Your `logging` properties in your `application.properties` are useless because you included a `logback.xml`. That `logback.xml` doesn't contain any console logger so naturally there is no logging to the console. Include the console logger.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/console-logging-configuration/ and 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653062/how-can-i-configure-logback-to-log-different-levels-for-a-logger-to-different-de has helped me thanks for pointing that the logs can be sent to any kind of appender.